# Returning MySQL results as hash tables in Perl

Tags: mysql, perl, hashtable

In Perl I'm making an SQL query akin to the following:

```
SELECT `id`, `title`, `price` FROM `gamelist`
```

What I wish to do is take the result of this query and dump it into a hash table. I am using DBI and currently I only know how to do the following:

```
my %results;
my $count = 0;
while( @result = $statement->fetchrow() ){
    %results{'id'}[$count] = $result[0];
    %results{'title'}[$count] = $result[1];
    %results{'price'}[$count] = $result[2];
    $count++;
}
```

However I don't like using `$result[0]` and trusting that the first field will be the ID. I would much rather have something like:

```
my %results;
my $count = 0;
while( %result = $statement->fetchrow_as_hashtable() ){
    %results{'id'}[$count] = %result{'id'};
    %results{'title'}[$count] = %result{'title'};
    %results{'price'}[$count] = %result{'price'};
    $count++;
}
```

I tried looking around on Google but couldn't find many good answers built into DBI/Perl. I did find an open-source class that offered this functionality, but I feel like this should be possible without the use of someone else's class.

Comment: Google isn't the best place to search for help on random Perl features - as there's a lot of bad Perl info out there on the web. You'd be far better off searching at CPAN (http://metacpan.org/) or Perldoc (http://perldoc.perl.org/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about [`fetchrow_hashref`](https://metacpan.org/module/DBI#fetchrow_hashref)?

Answer (score 5):

```
while (my $result = $statement->fetchrow_hashref) {
        print $result->{id};
        print $result->{title};
        print $result->{price};
}
```

Use fetchrow_hashref to have the result directly in a hash

Comment: I assumed he would know how to use it, his question contains an example that basically works with a method name change and a dereference.

Answer (score 4):

Consult the `DBI` documentation for this use of `selectall_arrayref`:

```
 $rows = $dbh->selectall_arrayref($query, {Slice=>{}}, @params)
```

`$rows` is an Array of Hashes.